# ASP.NET Core Attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou migrando um projeto para ASP.NET Core 2.0, porém não estou conseguindo utilizar as seguintes rotas.

Mensagem de erro.

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**

**AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:**

ASP.Net WebAPI2

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    // api/sales/1 -> funciona
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        // Logic
    }   

    // api/sales?page=1&pageSize-20 -> funciona
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] PaginationHelper pagination)
    {
        // Logic
    }  

    // api/sales?me -> funciona
    [ActionName("Get")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMe(bool? me)
    {
        // Logic
    }  
}
```

ASP.Net Core 2.0

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    // api/sales/1 -> funciona
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        // Logic
    }   

    // api/sales?page=1&pageSize-20 -> não funciona
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] PaginationHelper pagination)
    {
        // Logic
    }  

    // api/sales?me=false -> não funciona
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetMe(bool me)
    {
        // Logic
    }  
}
```

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema algum tempo atras, no meu caso, se tratava de uma rotas apontando para dois métodos diferente em controllers diferentes

Comment: No meu caso, tenho apenas um controller, e está dando conflito em 
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] PaginationHelper pagination) 
e 
public IActionResult GetMe(bool me)

Answer (score 2):

Acho que localizei seu problema...
tente colocar um httpAtribut para o seu metodo, pois mesmo os dois esperado receber coisas diferentes o sistema de rotas nao consegue entender para qual é:

**funciona:**

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        //GET api/values
       [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("vazio");
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            return Ok(id);
        }
        [HttpGet("{xx}")]// coloque isso --------------------!!!!
        public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] string xx)
        {
            return Ok("funcionou c:");
        }

        // GET api/values/true
        [HttpGet("{me:bool}")]// e isso --------------------!!!!
        public IActionResult Get(bool me)
        {
            return Ok(!me);
        }
    }
```

**Nao funciona:**

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    //GET api/values
   [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("vazio");
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] string xx)
    {
        return Ok("não funcionou :c");
    }

    // GET api/values/true
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(bool me)
    {
        return Ok(!me);
    }
}
```

}

o erro que retorna indica que ele nao sabe qual metodo satisfazer entao acaba soltando uma exeption

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication1)
WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication1)
***Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(RouteContext context, IReadOnlyList candidates)***

Espero ter ajudado, me avise se não der certo!

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas não resolve o meu caso, este parametro me, serve como se fosse um filtro, nesta mesma classe no WEBAPI2, eu tenho um método 

//api/sales?active=true
[ActionName("Get")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetActive(bool? active)

que funciona da mesma forme que o api/sales?me

Vou dar mais uma estudada, e se for o caso, mudar o padrão das requisições.

Answer (score 0):

> Tem dois metodos com o mesmo numero de parametros e  o
>   mesmo nome então tem de mudar o nome de um

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SalesController : Controller
    {
        // api/sales/1 -> funciona
        [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            // Logic
        }   

        // api/sales?page=1&pageSize-20 -> não funciona
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("OutroNome")]  // <--- Tem dois metodos com o mesmo numero de parametros e  o mesmo nome então tem de mudar o nome de um
        public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] PaginationHelper pagination)
        {
            // Logic
        }  

        // api/sales?me=false -> não funciona

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetMe(bool me)
        {
            // Logic
        }  
    }
```